# Setting scroll flags using data binding in android

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to set the scroll flags in collapsing toolbar layout using data binding. This is what I am trying to achieve:

> app:layout_scrollFlags="@{isListEmpty ? snap : scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap}"

But it is giving the following error:

> Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg: Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. snap is missing it

So basically I just want to turn off the collapsing effect when the list is empty. I can achieve that in code but it would be really helpful if there was a way to achieve this using data binding in xml.

Comment: Try to provide *custom BindingAdapter* logic for that.

Comment: oh yeah ,that worked as expected. Thanks. Still I would like to know if this can be achieved without even writing custom binding adapter. Afterall all we want is to set the scrollbehaviour based on some condition, so when can't this be done in xml itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this using BindingAdapters. Although I would still like to know if this can be achieved only from xml so that we don't have to use any custom attributes.

So I added a custom attribute

```
 @BindingAdapter("set_scroll_flags")
public static void setCollapsingToolbarScroll(CollapsingToolbarLayout 
 collapsingToolbar, boolean isListEmpty) {

    if(isListEmpty)
    {
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
        toolbarLayoutParams.setScrollFlags(0);
        collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);
    }
    else
    {

        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams toolbarLayoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
        toolbarLayoutParams.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);
        collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(toolbarLayoutParams);
    }
}
```

The above code stops the collapsing effect when the list is empty and when the list is not empty it behaves according to the scroll flags you set(I used EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED, SNAP and SCROLL).

Then in the xml, in the CollapsingToolbarLayout use the attribute like below:

> set_scroll="@{isListEmpty}"

Where **'isListEmpty'** can be a variable in the data tag of xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with BindingAdapter. Like that:

1. Add binding adapter:

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("app:layout_scrollFlags")
    fun setLayoutScrollFlags(toolbar : Toolbar, flags : Int) {

    //toolbar is your toolbar within an AppBarLayout
    val params = toolbar.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
    params.setScrollFlags(flags);
    toolbar.layoutParams = params
}
```

2. Replace code in your xml:

```kotlin
    app:layout_scrollFlags="@{viewModel.flags}"
```

3. If/else statements in in xml code is a bad practice (in spite of you can see it in Android documentation, this practice is a breakdown of single responsibility
   principle because view decide which flag to set according to boolean variable).

Set your flags on activity/fragment side as integers:

```kotlin
if(isListEmpty) {
    viewModel.setFlags(snap) 
} else {
    viewModel.setFlags(scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap)
}
```

So you will not hold any "Android related" data like reference on flag in view model. For view model it will be just an integer variable.

Hope it'll help)

Comment: thanks for posting your answer I did exactly the same and it worked.